# Any program for turning a multi-line PowerShell script into an encoded command?

Tags: powershell, minify

> Any program for turning a multi-line PowerShell script into an encoded command?

I've a PowerShell script that I want to convert into an encoded command. This usually requires that the script be turned into a single statement, with sub-statements separated by `;`.

Is there any program for turning a multi-line PowerShell script into a Base64 encoded command that can be run using `powershell.exe -EncodedCommand <cmd>`?

**PS script**:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$param1
    )

    $a = 10
    $b = 5
    $c = $a + $b
    Write-Host "$a + $b = $c"
    function f($a, $b) {
        if ($a -lt $b) {
            return $a
        } 
        return $b
    }

    Write-Host "(f $a $b) = $(f $a $b)"
} -ArgumentList "HelloWorld"
```

**powershell.exe -EncodedCommand**:

```
$DebugPreference = 'Continue'

$content = Get-Content "$file"
Write-Debug "Content: $content"

$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($content)
$b64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
Write-Debug "Base64: $b64"

powershell.exe -EncodedCommand "$b64"
```

**Error**:

```
At line:1 char:118
+ ... r(Mandatory=$false)][string]$param1     )      $a = 10     $b = 5     ...
+                                                                ~~
Unexpected token '$b' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:129
+ ... =$false)][string]$param1     )      $a = 10     $b = 5     $c = $a +  ...
+                                                                ~~
Unexpected token '$c' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:146
+ ...     )      $a = 10     $b = 5     $c = $a + $b     Write-Host "$a + $ ...
+                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'Write-Host' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that $expression is of type [ScriptBlock]

```
$expression = {Write-Output "Hello, World!"}
```

or in case you have a multiline script the script in a file

```
$expression = get-content .\MyScriptFile.ps1
```

or in any case you have a multi line string

```
$expression = 
@"
    Write-Output "Hello, World!";
    Write-Output "Another line";
"@;
```

**Note:** remember to put ; (semicolon) at the end of each statement line

you should then be able to do this

```
$commandBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($expression)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($commandBytes)
```

$encodedCommand can then be passed to powershell like

```
powershell.exe -EncodedCommand $encodedCommand
```

**Note:** you may hit some length limit, it is not due to the powershell infrastructure itself but in the way the comman line interpreter handle the parameters (command line on windows has a max length of 32767 char in total if i well remember, there should be additional restriction on the length of a single parameter as well depending on the system you are running this on.

Comment: Thank you, can you show how to turn my multi-line script into a script block, so that I can encode and execute it? If I just convert the script directly, execution fails.

Comment: Thanks for your help and feedback. I've updated my question. I still get an error. Can you spot any error in my code?

Comment: try put ; (semicolon) at the end of each line in your script

Comment: That works! However, I'm unsure exactly what needs to end with `;` and what does not. For example, `$a = 10` needs to end with a semicolon, while `param(..)`, `function f($a, $b) { ... }`, and `return $b` do not? Do you know of any program that automates this?

Comment: it's the language syntax. try to see if some linter or some smart editor can help you with warnings on where to put what. i'm afraid that it is quite hard that a program exists to fix your code in the general case. because it may end up changing the meaning of the program. maybe something can exist that fix very specific cases. but i'm uanaware of any of it, Please Up Vote if this helped you

Comment: Already gave you +1 - I've also accepted the answer. Please add `try put ; (semicolon)` to your answer, as that is an essential part of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from @mosè-bottacini's answer, to successfully encode/decode a multiline script try adding the `-Raw` flag when using `Get-Content` such as below:

```
$expression = Get-Content -Path .\MyScriptFile.ps1 -Raw
```